# Eclipse for C++ asks for Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, ide

I don't understand why this is happening. I installed Eclipse for C/C++ from this source: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/neonr

Then why does it ask me to get JRE or JDK?

This might be a really silly question, but I just don't get why it would require Java to be installed if I have specifically installed the Eclipse for C/C++!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse itself is written in Java, and so needs a JRE to be able to run.